# Função reset form em JS não funciona

Tags: javascript, formulário

O botão limpa o form mas não realiza o resto das funções

```
function reset() {
        var form   = document.getElementById("form");
        var nome   = document.form.nome.value;

        var set = confirm("Deseja apagar os dados do formulário?");
        if (set == true) {
            alert('Os campos do formulário foram resetados!');
            document.form.reset();
            document.form.nome.focus();
        }
    }

<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" onclick="reset();">Limpar</button>
```

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" onclick="reset();">Limpar</button>

Comment: Que "resto das funções" está a falar ?

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando como nome de função um nome de um [método nativo do JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp). Isso está gerando um tipo de conflito. Ao clicar no botão será chamada a função nativa `reset()` do JS resetado o formulário e não chamada a função que você deu o mesmo nome de `reset`.

> Procure dar nomes à funções e variáveis onde você tenha certeza que
>   não são nomes de funções ou métodos nativos ou palavras reservadas da
>   linguagem. Como a linguagem é no idioma inglês, uma boa saída para evitar
>   conflitos é dar nomes em português mesmo.

O que você tem que fazer é dar um nome diferente à função, pode ser `Reset` (primeira letra em maiúsculo, porque o JS diferencia maiúscula de minúscula) ou outro nome que quiser (que não seja reservado pela linguagem). No exemplo abaixo eu mudei pra `resetar`.

Além do que, já que você atribuiu o formulário à variável `form`, não precisa de `document`, caso contrário vai dar erro. Então deve remover esses `document`.

Pode também simplificar o `if` apenas com `if(set)` em vez de `if(set == true)`. A variável sozinha no `if` já indica que deve ser `true` (tal como `!set` indica que deve ser `false`):

```js
function resetar() {
   var form   = document.getElementById("form");
   var nome   = form.nome.value;

   var set = confirm("Deseja apagar os dados do formulário?");
   if (set) {
      alert('Os campos do formulário foram resetados!');
      form.reset();
      form.nome.focus();
   }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
   <input type="text" name="nome">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" onclick="resetar();">Limpar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

O HTML tem essa função nativa.

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

Caso você queira inserir uma confirmação, você pode interceptar a função de reset da seguinte forma:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('reset', function(e) {
  if(confirm("Do you really want to reset the form?")) {
    alert('Os campos do formulário foram resetados!');
  } else {
    e.preventDefault(); // Previne que a ação de reset seja executada;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="#">
  Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  Pin: <input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="4"><br>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click on the reset button to reset the form.</p>

</body>
</html>
```